# How to build android project using ant, when i referenced some jre libs

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ant

I used eclipse to develop my android app and used JRE System Library in the project. and i can  build the project using Eclipse. but i could not build it using ant. it could not found the classes in the JRE System Library. How can i add the JRE System Library to the ant build path?

Comment: John, could you perhaps post the error message for us so we can see what's going on? It might be that there's something someone could spot that you might have missed. Those error messages can be confusing at times!

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse doesn't create all the files you need to be able to run the project from the command-line. Might I suggest http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBuildAnt/article.html as a reference that will guide you through the steps to correctly configure Ant and use it from the command-line.

Comment: I refered to the article you gave me. It did not work. I still run into the error of "cannot find symbol".

Comment: Could you perhaps give us a bit more information? "Cannot find symbol" can mean so many things.